# How to get lastest result for each of distinct list?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table.

I can get distinct products and brands:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product, brand FROM list
```

And after it in Django I get the latest price:

for x in query:

```
SELECT price FROM list 
WHERE product = x.product AND brand = x.brand
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 1
```

How can I get all of it by one query?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and its expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Do you want to do this in ORM?

Comment: I want it in SQL or ORM, it doesn't matter now, I need only idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT product, brand, FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY product, brand ORDER BY ...) AS latest_price
FROM list
```

Comment: Strange, but it works slower than code in subject (first: distinct, and then a lot of little queries in a cycle)

Comment: @themis if possible, try adding a compound index over `product` and `brand`